# How to wait for data to be loaded before calling getState() in redux

Tags: javascript, redux, thunk

I have an action, `userAction`, that will call an API to load data from the database, and I want to use that data within a separate action, `calcAction`, so that I can post to an API with the data from `userAction` but when I call `getState()` in `calcAction` I get the initial state. How do I make sure that `getState()` will only get the state once the `userAction` has loaded the data from the database?

My `calcReducer` looks like this:

```
export const getAllCharReq = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { userData } = getState();
  axios.post('/api/character', userData).then((res) => {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ALL_CHAR_REQ,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  });
};
```

The `userAction` is called in the app component so that it loads the user data when first accessing the website. And the `calcAction` is called in `componentDidMount()` of a child component so that I can get the relevant data only when the component is accessed. So this is only a problem if a user loads this child component first. If a user were to navigate to this child component then the `userData` is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it inside of your thunk by executing the fetch only when the `userData` is present.

```
export const getAllCharReq = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { userData } = getState();
  if (userData) {
    axios.post("/api/character", userData).then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ALL_CHAR_REQ,
        payload: res.data
      });
    });
  } else {
    dispatch({
      type: "ERROR",
      payload: "No user data found"
    });
  }
};
```

You can also pass the `userData` from your component as an argument to the action creator, which is what I would recommend if it's doable with your app structure.  Within the component, you would know not to dispatch the thunk unless the `userData` is loaded.

```
export const getAllCharReq = (userData) => (dispatch) => {
  axios.post("/api/character", userData).then((res) => {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ALL_CHAR_REQ,
      payload: res.data
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: I can pass the userData as an argument, but if the userAction has not yet loaded the data, then it will still be empty regardless of passing the argument. I could check before I call the calcAction, but I don't see how that would make it different from checking within calcAction. I should have mentioned this before but I have a isLoaded field in userData. is there a way to wait for this to be true before making the post request?